# SQL Query via RabbitMQ

Tags: sql-server, rabbitmq

Is there an existing way to get a message from RabbitMQ and to use it to create an SQL query such as an "INSERT INTO"? For example, take the data that a webservice retrieves to a client (that data must go through Rabbit as well) and insert into a MS-SQL Server the data that the client is supposed to get.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much any language can talk to RabbitMQ. There is also a [powershell module](https://github.com/mariuszwojcik/RabbitMQTools) built for it.

For your needs, I've found the following [link](https://port1433.com/2017/07/21/messaging-queuing-for-the-dba-sending-data-out-into-the-world/) which demonstrates how you can set up rabbitmq with sql server.

I would suggest creating a sandbox example on your local machine using the link as a guide so that you can get familiar with RabbitMQ and its setup.

Hopefully that will provide you with the knowledge you need to solve your current problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it helped me with some of the doubts that I had but I'm still stuck in the main problem. I need something that works almost the other way around, and I don't know if that's even possible.